# Monogame|XNA Draw a black screen with a transparent circle at a specific location

Tags: screen, geometry, transparent, monogame

I try for some time to create a game.
But at the very beginning, I am stuck.
I just want to draw a black screen with a transparent circle overlaying it.
*I have searched a solution on a lot of french sites, but no responses*

**I drew you two images to show you what I want.**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/eKJ2Ni9.png?1]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/2RA0NWa.png?1]

**  Thank you for taking the time to read, and your help**

Comment: I've tried to make a full black image (1366x768)
A black square (75x75) with transparent circle in the middle, and it follow the player. Of course, the player is within the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (physically) can't have a PNG with a transparent hole that moves around.

I mean, try it yourself. Take a piece of paper, cut out a hole in the paper. While you can do that, you can't move the hole around. You'd need a new piece of paper.

You'll need to use a shader for this, that renders everything on the screen black, apart from a circle at the players position. Pretty basic post-processing shader.

Pseudo code (in C#, needs to be translated to HLSL):

```
foreach (var pixel in allPixels)
{
    bool drawAsBlack = pixel.Position.DistanceFrom(player.PositionCenter) > RANGE_RADIUS;
    if (drawAsBlack)
        return Color.Black;
    else
        return pixel.Color;
}
```

Something like that, obviously translated into HLSL, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I'll try it! :)